# Initialize std::vector<std::string> from a C style string array

Tags: arrays, string, c++11, constructor

I have the following array:

```
static const char * const names[] = { "Banana", "Apple", "Kiwi" }
```

Is it possible to construct a `std::vector<std::string>` from this with a simple constructor call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, easily, using the iterator-pair constructor:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> v(std::begin(names), std::end(names));
```

Comment: Cool! I did not know that it was possible to get the end pointer programatically

Comment: @galinette: Yes, it's quite easy, since the array size is part of the array type.

Comment: @galinette: No, it works with mutable arrays just as well: `int a[] = {1, 2, 3}; std::vector<int> v(std::begin(a), std::end(a));`